# Android : Contacts Content Uri?

Tags: android, uri, contacts

How to display the Contacts by content Uri. I know the contacts content uri `Contacts.CONTENT_URI` But, these content uri is differ from Version of SDK and API and also, i wan to know the content uri for all the versions. Because, i'm going to make one application like version independent of contact. Any one list out the content uri for all version of contacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only two content providers in the Android SDK for contacts: `Contacts` and `ContactsContract`. The latter is for use on Android 2.x and higher. However, each of those have multiple `CONTENT_URI` values, depending upon what facets of the data you are trying to interact with.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Contacts/Pick) demonstrating how to choose between two of those `CONTENT_URI` values via reflection in a static initializer.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Contacts/Spinners) demonstrating how to choose between two of those `CONTENT_URI` values via conditional class loading in a static initializer.

Comment: I want to list out all the details in contacts. How can i done this? Which content uri will i use. And, If i want to use this in version independent means, please specify that code.